# How to write multiple variables to a file with python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write multiple variables in one file. 
And would like to avoid to write all the variables and their type seperately.

I created the varibales with:

```
for i in range(100):
    globals()['doc%s' %i] = 5.*i
```

to write it to the file:

```
df = open("test.csv")
df.write("%0.10.f;%0.10.f" % (doc1, doc2))
```

But i would like to avoid to write within the last line all 100 names with the types.

Is this possible? Does anyone have an idea? 
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand - you want to avoid doing what the last line does?  You could delete that line...although it doesn't write the types...

Comment: Are you sure you mean "avoid"?

Comment: It's worth noting that you're only ever writing one line -- one long line.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are dynamically creating variables in the first place. There is really never a good reason to do this. Just create a single `doc` dict, and then you can write that out to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use 100 variables for this. Instead, use a list with 100 values in it. Then you can simply iterate over the list (or pairs of values from the list) and write the values out as you go.

```
doc = [5.*i for i in range(100)]
pairs = zip(*[iter(doc)]*2)
with open("test.csv") as df:
    for a, b in pairs:
        df.write("{0.10f};{0.10f}\n".format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must generate your variables in such a way, you can use a similar `globals` for-loop to dynamically retrieve the variables again.

For example:

`data = [globals()['doc%s' % i] for i in range(100)]`

puts the variables (doc0 ... doc99) into a list named `data`. You can then manipulate the list to print it in a format you want.

```
formatted_data = ["%0.10f" % point for point in data]
df = open("test.csv", "wb")
df.write(";".join(formatted_data))
df.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

use eval()

```
for i in range(100):
    globals()['doc%s' % i] = 5. * i

df = open("test.csv", mode='w')

for i in range(100):
    df.write("%0.10f;" % eval('doc%s' % i))
```

try it yourself. (My python version 2.7.8)